# high lag in telegram.botframework.com

Tags: botframework, telegram-bot

There is a well known problem which is botframework has high response time. However, we have launched a bot in the market using botframework (C#) and after some analysis, we found that requests to the `telegram.botframework.com` (and sometimes `state.botframework.com`) are so slow in average (as you can see in the following image):

[image]

Why this time should be high? Is this problem specific for Telegram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this problem came from telegram as shown in the following image:

[image]

You can follow the details from [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2563).